# RabbitMq: Listener and publisher thread with different routing key to direct exchange

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, amqp

I am trying to implement a scenario.
One of the component of my app system needs to send and receive data from same direct exchange but with two different routing key.

```
So is there any thing I need to consider such as: 
Sharing of variables
    such as connection,channel,
Data flow to correct listener
```

One more thing two components of my app system uses same direct exchange to publish data but uses different routing key. So is it safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For guidance around threading then take a look at the [.net client documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.0.4/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.0.4-user-guide.pdf), specifically section 2.9 entitled `Threading, deadlocks, and associated restrictions on
consumers`.

The summary is to create one instance of `IConnection`, the create a channel (`IModel`) per thread.

In terms of how you use your queues etc...you will need to ensure that the logic is correct for what you want to achieve.